# Styling divs to align correctly

Tags: html, css

I think I don't perfectly understand inline, block, float, etc. and was hoping for some help. I'm trying to achieve this setup:

[image]

The idea is to display the most common languages our clients use. I want to have a block that has the top 5 most common, with the most common getting a spotlight section. Then just list the rest of the languages underneath.

However, my code just pushes everything to the left, and the lets the rest of the page (like the footer) next to it. I want the top language and the next 4 to be next to each other, in the center of the screen, without affecting the page below it.

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    transition: all ease .5s;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(58,58,58);
}

#footer ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #666;
}

#footer li {
    float: left;
}

#footer li p {
    display: block;
    color: #555;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 7px 16px;
}

br {
    display: block;
}

#footer li a {
    display: block;
    color: #555;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#footer li a:hover {
    display: block;
    color: #555;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#language-stats li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 13px;
    margin: 6px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: rgb(58,58,58);
    background-color: rgb(210,210,210);
    font-weight: bold;
}

#top-5 {
  width: 600px;
}

#top-1 {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#next-4 {
  float: left;
  width: 350px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

  <div id="languages">
    
    <div id="top-5">
      <h3>Top Languages</h3>
      
      <div id="top-1">
        <svg height="70" width="60">
          <circle cx="30" cy="40" r="30" fill="#CECECE" />
          <text x="18" y="53" style="font-size: 40;
                                     stroke: #fff;
                                     fill: #fff">1</text>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div id="next-4">
        <ul>
          <li>2: Example</li>
          <li>3: Example</li>
          <li>4: Example</li>
          <li>5: Example</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="language-stats">
      <h3>Language Stats</h3>
      <ul id="language-stats-list">
        <li>Languages Represented: 37</li>
        <li>Coolest Language: Example</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <br />
  <hr />
  <div id="footer">
    <ul>
        <li><p><a href="#">Download CSV</a></p></li>
        <li><p><a href="#">Link to dictionary</a></p></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

(You have to see the snippet in full page to witness the issue.)

What am I missing to have the cleaner layout I desire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, if you'd like the *language-stats* div to appear under your floated *top-1* and *next-4* elements, you'll just need to add the style `clear: left` to language-stats.  This will effectively line-break it below the other two elements.

Additionally, you'll want to add `margin: 0px auto` to the styles of the *top-5* div- this will equally space the left and right margins of your 600px-wide element and center it on the page.

Comment: If I use that same "margin: 0px auto" tip on other tags it doesn't seem to work. For example, I added a <p> tag below the <svg>, and wrapped them both in a <div>, added that same line--yet it won't center.

Comment: For the auto-sized left & right margins to center an object, the element needs to have a fixed width.  Block elements like divs and p tags have a 100% width by default, so giving them automatically spaced left & right margins will not have a visible effect until you add a fixed width (like your 600px-wide _top-5_).  If all you want to do is center the text within those 100% wide elements, `text-align: center` is the way to go.